# Authenticate user in a controller and send session to frontend

Tags: authentication, grails, authorization

On backend in a controller, I want to log in a user. Then I want to render a view `render(view: '/my-view')` where the user will be authenticated already.

**Scenario**

1. A user is given a **link**.
2. He goes to this **link**.
3. Backend redirects the link to a **controller**.
4. **Controller** creates a temporary account for the user and authenticates him.
5. **Controller** renders a view and **???? somehow sends the session to frontend ????**.

How can I send the session to the frontend?

Comment: instead of saying I will offer why dont you put the bounty on the queston :)

Comment: The bounty button will be available in 2 days and not right now. Grrr. :D

Comment: @halfer, you seem like a keen editor. What about helping me to get the right answer. `;)`

Comment: I get a lot of that from 1-rep users, as if asking people at random on Stack Overflow would result in finding the best person to answer their particular question. I don't understand it.

Comment: @halfer, Whast does it mean a `1-rep user`?

Comment: Er, well you're a 4,556-rep user `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Define front end ?

> Backend redirects the link a controller. Controller creates a
>   temporary account for the user and authenticates him.

This is how I am doing it sockets does authentication, access that user's http session from backend and puts in there that they have logged in. I then send a socket trigger back to front end html to say all ok
at this point gsp gets response from sockets and says aha redirect to `/site/hello`

> Controller renders a view and ???? somehow sends the session to frontend ????

This /site/hello now checks for specific session and well user is also now logged in too..  the session details was set by backend when user authenticated and not front end session

in gsp you can do

```
<g:set var="something" scope="session"/>
```

But I think what i have described is what you need to do

If you need helping user session details it is all quite easy i don't have it to hand

but from gsp when connecting to sockets i send `'${session.id}'` which then i look up and bind back to user .....

Also note --- there is catch here, when user is not authenticated they have primary session, when they authenticate through spring security they are actually given a new session id. This is due to security issues but I have got around that with checking `session.username` which i set upon login and this now matches '${params.encryptedUsername}'  decrypted on backend..

Ahh it's rolling back.. there is a concurrent hashmap which contains `username,session` and from that When i get `Decrypted.username` I get hashMap which the value is user http session to which i poke and do things with ...

I can give you my code but then that is a lot of work above is the steps in one way of how you go about it

So to answer your question, this is under grails 3:
Enable Spring security session listener in [application.groovy](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.groovy#L4)

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
```

Add [CustomSecurityEventListener.groovy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/master/src/main/groovy/security/CustomSecurityEventListener.groovy) class to your app, remove the loginCacheAttempt, unless you wish to use it refer to build.gradle for that stuff and the related service etc in that demo app.

This then calls [SessionListener](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/main/groovy/security/SessionListener.groovy) provided in that same folder and adds user with session id to the sessions synchronised map declared at the top of SessionListener

Now in my websockets when I register a user:

```
String sessionId = userSession.userProperties.get("sessionId") as String
                def userHttpsession = SessionListener.sessions.find{it.key==sessionId}?.value
userHttpsession.username = username
userHttpsession.password = password
```

**This is still pre-authentication and primary session**

I send a trigger to tell sockets to refresh gsp page to another window.location.href

In that location controller action i authenticate session details and invalidate session details

```
registerService.authenticateUser(user, session.password)
```

This way of doing things appears to work fine without the complications, there is an encrypted user which is sent as part of initial socket transaction to ensure/verify session.user matches encrypted user (for logged in user)

Comment: Vahid thanks for trying to help me out. :) I don't understand very much, though. Currently, my biggest issue is how to create a Spring Security session....

Comment: nah you need to implement listeners to work along side your spring security but it is a little trickier since you need to bind into HttpSessionListener, can't recall exact workings. Will provide some code or steps later. Take a look here https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/tree/master/src/main/groovy/security it kind of covers it but actually the concurrent hashmap etc was a new concept after hitting issues with session renewals pre/post authentication

Comment: Try to follow above it is all rather complex stuff and well you will need to start with something like that and ask questions rather than expect to be given the entire code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the programmatic login takes care of the session too.

`springSecurityService.reauthenticate(email, password)`